# How to test cookies with Rspec and Capybara in a feature test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, cookies, rspec

I am using Rails 4.2 now.

My test file looks like:

```
# spec/features/my_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
feature 'MyFeature', type: :feature do
  describe 'MyPage' do
    it 'Saved the cookie' do
      visit my_path
      expect(response.cookies[:my_cookie]).to eq('some_value')
    end
  end
end
```

In the controller, I set a cookie as: `cookies[:my_cookie] = 'some_value'`, so in the spec file, I will test if the cookie has been saved after access the special path as above, but failed. The `response` is only used in the controller, but how to test cookies in this case?

Reference:

> https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/cookies

Comment: That seems like something you should test for in a controller spec, and not a feature spec.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I want to do a cookies test in a feature spec, but `respond` seems only can be used in a controller test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gem can do it:

> [show_me_the_cookies](https://github.com/nruth/show_me_the_cookies)